# How can i convert a tensorflow.js model saved from google's teachablemachine to a keras.hdf5 or tflite model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

The saved tensorflow.js model is comprised of the following 3 file.

1. metadata.json
2. model.json
3. weights.bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TensorFlow.js converter library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter#getting-started) to convert between formats

It does not convert to TFLite, but it should allow you to convert from [TensorFlow.js to Keras](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter#javascript-to-python). for example:

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format tfjs_layers_model \
    --output_format keras \
    tfjs_model/model.json \
    keras_model/
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked i shall test the converted model